# How to work with JWT with Django and Redux

Tags: django, rest, redux, jwt

So I've recently learned about JWT authentication using Django Rest Framework and now, I would like to use it. Setting things up with DRF was easy, but now I'm facing a problem : I have no idea how to consume the given tokens ( access and refresh ) with redux. I also have no idea how to retrieve a user based on the given tokens.
Here is what I have for the moment.
My actions :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  LOGIN_STARTED,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILURE,
} from './types.js';


const loginStarted = () => ({
  type: LOGIN_STARTED,
})

const loginFailure = error => ({
  type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
  payload: {
    error: error
  }
})

const loginSuccess = (access_token, refresh_token) => ({
  type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    access_token: access_token,
    refresh_token : refresh_token
  }
})


export const authLogin = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(loginStarted);
  axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/", {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
  .then( res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch(loginFailure(err.data));
  })
}
```

And my reducer looks like this :

```
import {
  LOGIN_STARTED,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILURE,
} from '../actions/types.js';


const initialstate = {
  access: undefined,
  refresh: undefined,
  error: {}
}

export default function(state=initialstate, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        access: action.type.access_token,
        refresh: action.type.refresh_token,
      }
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.error
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Use the access token to query the API for the logged in user. Like a `/me` endpoint.

Comment: @KevinLee How can I do that ?

Comment: You're going to have to: 1. Create new endpoint in django. If you're unsure how to do that, I you should read the django documentation, complete the tutorials, and read the django rest framework documentation. 2. Create a new action in your frontend to hit your django endpoint, just like the authLogin action.